# Does kubernetes come with docker by default

Tags: docker, kubernetes

According to this [link](https://www.docker.com/kubernetes) docker is supporting kubernetes on linux, mac and windows. I can't make out whether or not kubernetes is installed within docker like swarm is. So is it true that with a normal install of docker it will also install kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

I would not say it'll be installed but you'll get the chance to do it if you want to.

**Here's the about page:**

> Version 18.05.0-ce-win67 (18263)
>   Channel: edge
>   0c7f1aa

**If you navigate to the Settings page (Docker CE for windows in my case), and select to enable Kubernetes, this is what you get:**

[image: Kubernetes Opt-in]

**If you choose to install it...**

[image: Kubernetes intallation]

**Wait a little...**

[image: Kubernetes installation completed]

After completion you can use your kubernetes - through regular `docker stack *` commands - to run a single-node cluster locally while developing. Which is really nice!

You can use the kubectl CLI directly also. It should be already in your PATH. The CLI is located at `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin`.

Hope this helps!