# Installing docker and kubernetes on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes

I have installed both kubernetes and docker on Ubuntu in an effort to have the similar dev environment that I have on my windows 10 machine so I can debug a problem with extra \r\n on my kubernetes secrets.

How do you perform [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072235/does-kubernetes-come-with-docker-by-default) step on Ubuntu?

I think I need something like `kubectl config use-context docker-for-desktop` which doesn't work on Ubuntu or configure kubectl to point to the right docker port.

How do I get kubernetes configured?

I am on Ubuntu 18.10.
Docker version (Installed with directions from [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)):

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.0
 API version:       1.38 (downgraded from 1.39)
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        4d60db4
 Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:49:01 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Mon Oct  1 14:25:33 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Kubectl version:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.2", GitCommit:"17c77c7898218073f14c8d573582e8d2313dc740", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-24T06:54:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Answer (score 2):

Docker Enterprise Edition(EE) for Ubuntu is the only container platform with a built-in choice of orchestrators (Docker Swarm and Kubernetes), operating systems, (Windows and multiple Linux distributions), and supported infrastructure (bare metal, VMs, cloud, and more) -https://store.docker.com/editions/enterprise/docker-ee-server-ubuntu

[Here’s](https://forums.docker.com/t/is-there-a-built-in-kubernetes-in-docker-ce-for-linux/54374) an answer confirming the same

> Docker’s Community Edition engine for Linux does not include built-in
>   kubernetes capabilities. We say
>
> We have added Kubernetes support in both Docker Desktop for Mac and
>   Windows and in Docker Enterprise Edition (EE).
>
> You can build a Kubernetes cluster yourself on top of one or more CE
>   engines, though. For some guidance, you can visit the setup
>   documentation at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/scratch/